# Integrity check Dockerfile entrypoint layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile, checksum, data-integrity, docker-entrypoint

I'm wondering if there is a way I can perform an integrity check of a containers entrypoint. The images are used in micro-services and easily modified by the teams running them.

Considering each layer packaged as a tar.gz with a SHA256 sum, is there possible way that I could ensure that this `ENTRYPOINT` layer is as expected, and is also the final command to the image?

I'm thinking I can find the layers checksum, but not sure how I could check the actual entrypoint to the checksum.The problem im trying to solve is ensuring that a specific script is run which starts the service, but also performs some events/scripts but teams often override this.

Comment: A container can't usually run `docker` commands.  If your image contained the `sha256sum` command then you could run that against the container filesystem, but if someone modified this with a bind mount they could also replace the sum file.